# sccm 2007 SP2 SUP settings

Tags: wsus, sccm

When I try to add a SUP by adding a new site system. I try to select products but there are only older products in there. For example there isnt any office 2007 just 2003 and the only os are XP and windows vista.
Any ideas how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

When you add the primary SUP, it will only have the applications that are listed in WSUS.  This list is updated the next time WSUS syncs with its upstream (i.e. Microsoft).  After WSUS is sync'd, you can look inside its configuration and see all of the new apps that can be downloaded.  Even though you're using SCCM to send out updates, you have to use the WSUS console to identify which updates you want to download.  After the WSUS database is made current, SCCM must also sync its own database.  This can be manually commanded from the Software Updates node or will happen periodically on its own.

Note that if this is a secondary SUP, it should be getting all of its settings from the upstream site.